# I bought a Floureon BM-800, and neweer 48v phantom power, but still no sound?

Tags: microphone

I bought a floureon bm-800 under the impression it was a plug and go and it didn't work, so upon further investigation i have found some versionS require phantom power. however, even after buying and putting an inline phantom power box from neweer on there, i'm not receiving anything at all? is there some kind of set up that is required but not listed on box of either component?

Comment: Silly question maybe, but do you have the power supply connected and switched-on for the Phantom Power box?

Comment: If yes, then please list which interfere and recording software you are using.

Comment: I bought one of those just for the purposes of answering interwebz questions about them - they do work just fine with phantom & a matching XLR cable rather than the one it comes with, so the suspects right now are cabling & the Neewer. If you could provide links to the Neewer spec & pics, & tell us what cabling you're using, that may help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Buzzing, Hissing input level issues BM-700 BM-800 NW-800 Neewer/Floureon](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/44184/buzzing-hissing-input-level-issues-bm-700-bm-800-nw-800-neewer-floureon)